# meta http-equiv X-UA-Compatible

Tags: html, xhtml

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >`

the above line of code forces the browser to make

Document mode to IE 9 standard and 
Browser mode to IE 9 Compatiblity mode

How can i make Document mode to IE 9 standard and browser mode to IE 9 mode

Comment: I HAVE DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

this works for me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>    
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: With this also my page is going to  Browser mode  IE 9 Compatiblity

Comment: does it make a difference if you change your doctype to <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I made as your doctype,still it is rendering in  IE 9 Compatiblity

Comment: What is the meaning of IE=edge?

Comment: What is the meaning  of value="IE=EmulateIE8" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other links or scripts above your X-UA-Compatible meta tag in your `<head>`? If so this might be causing the problem.

Also make sure to check the compatibility settings in your browser itself by going to:

Tools --> Compatability View Settings

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible explanations, such as HTTP headers overriding the `meta` tag, domain name being blacklisted by Microsoft, or your local admin having forced IE to Compatibility mode. For a description of some possibilities and possible cures, check out [IE8 and IE9 Complications](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8) in “Activating Browser Modes with Doctype”.