# IE=edge and IE=EmulateIE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http-headers, xhtml

see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230970/meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible)

In that context

What is the meaning of value="IE=edge"?

What is the meaning of value="IE=EmulateIE8" ?

Comment: How is this related to c# ?

Comment: What would you *guess* EmulateIE8 means?

Comment: TFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565650(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: awesome explanation here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IE=edge` simply tells IE to use the last version of the rendering engine.

It's [documented here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx), just like the less useful (in my opinion) `IE=EmulateIE8`.

`IE=edge` helps you avoiding some "compatibility" behaviors. It makes IE9 more compatible with other modern engines.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305631/ie9-float-with-overflowhidden-and-table-width-100-not-displaying-properly) for example. I always start my HTML files with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```